# How to rerun failed test cases and add coverage in previous coverage?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-coverage

I am using Intellij in which i am runnning test cases but due to slow net some cases failed and i got some code coverage.

After i rerun the failed testcases , the test cases passed but then after new coverage came for these failed test cases.

I want to **add** this new coverage to the previous coverage data. How can i do that?

Comment: You could merge several coverage suites: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-between-code-coverage-suites.html

Comment: You didn't solve my problem as you said "I am not aware how this could be done directly with IntelliJ. I also think that using an IDE is the wrong answer here"

Answer (score 1):

A distinct non answer, as I am not aware how this could be done directly with IntelliJ. I also think that using an IDE is the wrong answer here.

When you are using "server based" solutions (relying on tools like SonarQube or TeamScale for example), then you can setup your environment so that all such coverage data get collected on a central server. And then that server can tell you about that "cumulative" coverage results.

Of course that requires more thought to setup the environment, but in return, you get a timeline for your data, and you enable yourself for many more options regarding collection/evaluation of such that.

Beyond that: your real problem are your *flaky* test cases. A test setup should give you *stable*, *robust* results. When network load affects you in such ways, then your testing strategy is wrong. Instead of having functional tests that rely on certain network properties (and fail on tight response times), you should rather go with

- isolated unit tests (that just exercise your code, and mock out all dependencies on network, file system, ...)
- dedicated functional/integration tests. These would really use network, database, ... but *not* fail on tight timeouts.